# Crear SettingController con Laravel y metodos update para atributos privados y publicos

Tags: php, mvc, controller, update, crud

os comento, tengo una tarea que no termino de entender muy bien, la verdad:

Tengo que crear un controlador con Laravel llamado SettingsController, la cosa es que con este controlador puedo actualizar la información pública o la información privada, por lo que tendría que tener métodos update en el controlador que tengo que crear.

Me han pasado un ejemplo de controlador y una estructura de la tabla usuarios.

### La clase RegisterController.php que tengo como ejemplo

```
 use IssueTokenTrait;

private $client;

public function __construct() 
{

    $this->client = Client::where('name', 'UNBLND Password Grant Client')->first();

}

public function exists(Request $request) 
{

    $request->validate([
          'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
    ]);

    return response()->json(['exists' => false]);
}

public function register(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);

    $u = User::create([
        'name' => request('name'),
        'email' => request('email'),
        'avatar' => str_random(10),
        'password' => Hash::make(request('password')),
    ]);

    $position = \Location::get(request('ip'));
    if ( is_numeric($position->latitude) && is_numeric($position->longitude) ) {
        \Log::info('Register user_id ' . $u->id . ' location: ' . $position->latitude . ',' . $position->longitude);
        Location::create([
            'user_id' => $u->id,
            'longitude' => $position->longitude,
            'latitude' => $position->latitude
        ]);
    }

    return $this->issueToken($request, 'password');
}
```

}

---

y aquí la estructura de la tabla de usuarios

```
 <?php
```

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
```

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->date('birth_date')->nullable();
        $table->integer('age_group_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('avatar');
        $table->string('avatar_hex', 7)->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('is_blocked')->default(false);
        $table->string('password')->nullable();
        $table->string('facebook_id', 50)->nullable();
        $table->text('facebook_token')->nullable();
        $table->string('twitter_id', 50)->nullable();
        $table->text('twitter_token')->nullable();
        $table->string('instagram_id', 50)->nullable();
        $table->text('instagram_token')->nullable();
        $table->string('public_info', 600)->nullable();
        $table->string('private_info', 600)->nullable();
        $table->boolean('is_privacy_important')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('is_ambassador')->default(false);
        $table->smallInteger('email_frequency')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->boolean('email_when_new_group')->default(true);
        $table->boolean('email_when_invited')->default(true);
        $table->boolean('email_when_welcome')->default(true);
        $table->boolean('email_when_unread')->default(true);
        $table->boolean('email_when_request')->default(true);
        $table->boolean('email_when_accept')->default(true);
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

}

a ver si me podéis decir por donde atacar, la verdad es que estoy un poco liado, la verdad es que estoy un poco liado con Laravel.

Answer (score 1):

El controlador que estás mostrando como ejemplo probablemente tenga poco que ver con lo que quieres hacer. Según entiendo necesitas crear un controlador que se encargue de lidiar con los ***settings*** de tu sistema y no con los usuarios. Estaría bueno que nos cuentes que esperas que haga este método `update` que comentás. (i.e "*updetear*" campos en una base de datos?, ¿Interactuar con algún modelo? etc..)

Si tu problema está más relacionado a cómo se arma un controlador en ***Laravel*** te recomiendo que te apegues a su paradigma y uses `artisan` y crees tu controller con el siguiente comando.

```
php artisan make:controller SettingsController
```

Agregandole el flag `--resource` te creará el controlador con los métodos ***REST*** y más.

Comment: El metodo update debe actualizar alunos datos de un usuario, por ejemplo, el nombre es privado y solo lo pueden ver personas que estén logueadas, pero en cambio el nick si es visible para todos, es un perfil de una aplicación de red social. Lo que he pensado es un update a la base de datos directamente, porque no tengo mucha información, así que no se me ocurre más que ir directo y por las bravas.